# Python check if attribute is none depending on string

Tags: python, django

I want to check if an attribute from a class is None. The attribute itself depends on some cases and is stored in a string "attribute_name". How can I check of the attribute is None? Something like:

```
hasattr(object, attribute_name)
```

but then not checking of the attribute exists in the model but if it has a value

Comment: Are you looking for [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hasattr` to check if the object has the specific attribute and need to check if the attribute value is `None` or not. So you can do this as following

```
hasattr(object, attribute_name) and getattr(object, attribute_name) is None
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```py
if getattr(object, attribute_name) is not None:
    # Your code here
```

Comment: What if the attribute is `False`? It wont enter the conditional block, but it should, because its not `None`.